# Calculate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt$ using Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

Calculate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt$ using Fourier transform. Unfortunately, we have not learned Plancherel's Theorem. 
The only other hint that was given is $$\mathcal{F}[f(t)]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1-\cos(\lambda\pi)}{\lambda^2},$$ where $$f(t)=\begin{cases}t+\pi&t\in[-\pi,0]\\\pi-t&t\in(0,\pi]\end{cases},$$ and $f(t)=0$ otherwise.
I know that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt,$$ and I know the answer is supposed to be $\pi/2$, but I am unsure of how to get started.

Comment: you didn't learn the Plancherel theorem but your learnt that $\mathcal{F}[f \ast g] = \mathcal{F}[f] \mathcal{F}[g]$ ? in that case $g(t) = \overline{f(t)}$ and $2 \pi h(0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}^{-1}_{[h]}(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega$ gives the Plancherel theorem. alternatively, tell us what you learnt :-)

Comment: Hint: Recall that $1-\cos(\lambda pi)=2\sin^2\frac{\lambda\pi}{2}$. Also the inverse Fourier transform is given by $f(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{2\pi i t\lambda}\mathcal{F}[f](\lambda)d\lambda$. Thus what can you say about $f(0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, thanks to the helpful comment from Frank Lu.

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt$$

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}t+\pi&t\in[-\pi,0]\\\pi-t&t\in(0,\pi]\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \mathcal{F}^{-1}\bigg[\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{(1-\cos\lambda\pi)}{\lambda^2}\bigg] & = 
        \mathcal{F}^{-1}\bigg[\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{(2\sin^2(\lambda\pi/2))}{\lambda^2}\bigg] \\
        \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{(2\sin^2\lambda)}{\lambda^2} & = \mathcal{F}\bigg[f(\frac{2}{\pi}t)\bigg] \\
        & = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\sin^2\lambda}{\lambda^2} \\
        \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}^{-1}[f(2t/\pi)] & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2\lambda}{\lambda^2}e^{i\lambda t}d\lambda
    \end{aligned}    
\end{equation*}
At $t=0$, we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2\lambda}{\lambda^2}d\lambda=\pi\Rightarrow\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}$$